# Kafka producers failing when one Kafka Broker goes down

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a kafka cluster with 4 brokers. We have setup the topic with the configuration
`replication.factor=3, min.insync.replicas=2`

We noticed that whenever a single broker fails, our producers start failing within 60-90 seconds with the below error

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 19 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for a-13
[ERROR] ERROR Parser:567 - org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 19 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for a-13
```

We have the below producer configs on the producer side.

```
acks=all, 
request.timeout.ms=120000
retry.backoff.ms=5000
retries=3
linger.ms=250
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=2
```

As per the configuration will the producer take atleast 6 minutes before failing? As request.timeout.ms=2 minutes and retries=3?

We do not have unclean leader election enabled. We are running Kafka 2.0 and the producer client version is 0.10.0.1.

We have the **replica.lag.time.max.ms** is set to 10s on the brokers. When the issue happened we noticed that the leader re-election happened within 40seconds. So I am confused why the producers are failing almost instantly when one broker goes down.

I can provide more info if required.

Comment: You set `acks=all`. Which requires all broker to be up, and why is your producer so low?

Comment: What do you mean by low?

Comment: The producer version. You are runnnig Kafka 2.0, and so your client version should be at least 0.11, but upgrade all the way would get better benefits

Comment: Yes the client version is very old but that is the system we inherited. I want to be sure if the version compatibility might be the one causing this issue.

Comment: It's possible...You would have to read the Kafka release notes. Then again, you're having timeout errors that are just related to temporal effects, so increasing at least `linger.ms` would be one possibility, or reducing the batch/buffer sizes

Answer (score 0):

You set `acks=all`, and failed to mention **which** broker is down.

Sounds like the failed broker hosted one of the topic's partitions, and the ack is failing.

Comment: Acks might be failing but based on the config on the producer it should wait for certain time (here 6 mins) before it exhausts the retries but we observe that it goes down within 60-90 seconds

Comment: That doesn't mean that the batch wont expire though... Have you tried using the idempotent producer introduced around Kafka 1.0?